# perl output doesnt showup in intellij (2019 with perl5 plugin - Camelcade) console - tried

Tags: perl, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to run perl scripts from Intellij(2019) with [Camelcade perl5 plugin](https://github.com/Camelcade/Perl5-IDEA/wiki) but it doesn't seem to run at all

running the script from the terminal works just fine

Here is the 'Run Configuration', am I missing something?
[image]

Comment: Is there no log?

Comment: Can you try with a simple "hello world" script? I tried the plugin (Ubuntu 20.04, perlbrew perl 5.30) and it works fine here